# How does the wavefunction look like for inverted oscillator potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, harmonic-oscillator, scattering

Suppose the inverted harmonic oscillator potential
$$H=\frac{p^2}{2m}-\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2$$
I'm looking for a form of solution for the case when $E<0$. It's clear that a scattering solution will exist. Suppose I shot a particle from the left-hand side, then How does the wavefunction would look like?

[image]

To my knowledge, it should look like this. But I'm not sure in the tunneling region.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16299/

Comment: I saw that It doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

The wave function may roughly look like this.

[image]

- At the classical turning points (marked by ¦)
  it is $\psi''(x)=0$.
- In the classical allowed range $\psi(x)$
  is oscillating around $0$.
- In the classically forbidden range $\psi(x)$
  is non-oscillating.

Comment: What about the amplitude?

Comment: @YoungKindaichi Amplitude ratio depends on many things (energy $E$, width of
forbidden region, boundary conditions). I assumed your scenario: an incident wave from the left. So you get a reflected wave back to the left, and a transmitted wave on the right. Therefore I've drawn the right amplitude smaller than the left amplitude,